# “docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version:" Error in python

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, apple-m1, rosetta-2

I have installed docker on M1 chip in Rosatta mode and Docker daemon is also running. When I try to execute `"docker.from_env()"` in my python code I’m getting this error

> “docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API
> version: (‘Connection aborted.’, FileNotFoundError(2, ‘No such file or
> directory’))”

Can someone help to resolve this issue? I tried reinstalling the docker multiple times and my docker is upto date also.

I tried reinstalling the docker multiple times and my docker is upto date also.

Comment: Can you verify that the standard docker environment variables are available within the python runtime?  They are documented here: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after recent env update.

In my case  the socket `/var/run/docker.sock` has gone. To fix the issue you have to create a symlink to the actual socket file ([doc.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/permission-requirements/#installing-symlinks))

```
> sudo ln -s -f /Users/<user>/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
> chmod +r /var/run/docker.sock # optional
```

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you!

Comment: I run container by colima on mac m1. It works for my situation. Thanks.
sudo ln -s -f /Users/david/.colima/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock